# Escape new line in triple quoted string - python

Tags: python, newline

I have following string

```
string = """
Hello/nWorld
123
HelloWorld
"""
```

But when I print it I get

```
Hello
World
123
HelloWorld
```

But I want to get

```
Hello/nWorld
123
HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `\` to escape the other `\` char:

```
string =  """
Hello\\nWorld
123
HelloWorld
"""
```

or have a "raw" string:

```
string =  r"""
Hello\nWorld
123
HelloWorld
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing exactly what you want it to do, at least on Linux:

```
>>> string = """
... Hello/nWorld
... 123
... HelloWorld
... """
>>> print(string)

Hello/nWorld
123
HelloWorld
```

Are you perhaps on a system that uses `/n` as newline?